# Amount field allowed - only digits 0-9, upto two decimal places and $

Tags: jquery, html, regex, validation

Hi
I have this Regex which now allows user to key-in only 0-9 digits and upto 2 decimal places. What modification has to be done to this regex to make it accept also '$'. 
[Example link for regex][1] 

regex:
this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d+\.?\d?\d?)?.*/g,'$1');

Answer (score 0):

Following your regex:

```
^(\d+\.?\d?\d?)?.*
```

You have to add `\$` symbol like this:

```
^(\$\d+\.?\d?\d?)?.*
  ^--- here, and escape the character
```

Btw, if you don't want to capture the dolar symbol you could do:

```
^(\$\d+\.?\d?\d?)?.*
```

Comment: I would probably write this as `^\$(\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)$`

Comment: I tried the same, but was not able to match it. http://js.do/syedsami/amount-validation

Comment: @user2229399 the regex is fine but your code expect a different regex. You just need to put the `\$` within the capturing group. Use this instead: `^(\$\d+\.?\d?\d?)?.*`. Have just updated the answer, don't forget to mark the question as solved if my answer answered to your question.